# page is loading very slow in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

Hello I have a webproject which I am hosting, the problem is that a specific page is loading very slow.
The reason is I guess the Jquery code where I am iterating through the lectures and I have more then 1200 lectures. I normally showed all lectures and filtered them with searching and then I thought it could be faster if I show nothing and only show it when someone is searching but it is still slow. Here is my html. Thank you in advance.

html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="container"><h1 style="text-align:center;">Not Dağılımları</h1>
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="container">

        <div class="form-group pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search form-control" placeholder="Ara">
        </div>
        <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
        <table style="background-color:white;"class="table table-hover results">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th >Hoca</th>
                <th>Fakülte</th>
        <th >Ders</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="warning no-result">
        <td><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Sonuç Yok</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>




<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".search").keyup(function () {
            $('tbody').find('tr').remove();
            var searchTerm = $(".search").val().toLowerCase();
            if (searchTerm.length>2){
            list=[]
            {%for lec in lecturer_list%}
            if( '{{lec}}'.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)){
                $('tbody').append('<tr><td><p><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#002855;" href="{% url 'distribution:lecturer_distribution' slug=lec.slug%}">{{lec.lecturer}}</a></p></td><td><p>{{lec.faculty}}</p></td><td style="color:white;">{%for ders in lec.lecture.all%}<a style="text-decoration:none;color:#002855;" href="{% url 'distribution:lecture_distribution' slug=ders.slug%}">{{ders.lecture}}</a>,{% endfor%}</td></tr>');
      }

            {%endfor%}
        }
        });
});

</script>

{% endblock content%}
```

**EDIT**
here is my lecturer model

```
class Lecturer(models.Model):
    lecturer=models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False)
    lecture=models.ManyToManyField(Lecture,blank=True)
    faculty=models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='department_for_lecturer')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.lecturer)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_lectures(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.lecture.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lecturer

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['lecturer']
```

views.py

```
class Index(generic.ListView):
    template_name='home.html'
    models=Lecturer
    queryset = Lecturer.objects.all()


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['lecturer_list'] = Lecturer.objects.order_by('lecturer')
        return context
```

Comment: Share your `Lecture` model and the view, likely this is the famous *N+1 problem*.

Comment: consider using Django Debug Toolbar (https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to check the number of SQL queries performed to render this view

Comment: Especially the `lec.lecture.all`, `lec.lecturer` and `lec.faculty` should be optimized. I'm also not convinced why you need JavaScript here to handle it like this. If you for example want to make a table more dynamic, it is better to render the table, and let JavaScript handle the table. It might also be better to use AJAX queries in case the load is really too much to fetch "pages". But 1'200 is not much, so I don't think these are necessary here.

Comment: I am not very familiar with AJAX therfor I used JS, but if AJAX is the only solution then I have to learn it.

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü: where does the `lec.lecturer` comes from (and `lec.faculty` and `lec.lecture.all`? These do not appear in your model, but are likely sources of inefficiency. Can you add the corresponding models/relations?

Comment: I added the wrong (lecture) model now I added the lecturer model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common *N+1 problem* where you fetch all the `Lecturer`s in one database query, but then for each `Lecturer`, you make extra queries to fetch the `lecture` objects, and the `faculty` objects related to it.

You can boost efficiency here with [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for one-to-one relations and many-to-one relations, and [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for one-to-many and many-to-many relations. So here you can work with:

```
class Index(generic.ListView):
    template_name='home.html'
    model = Lecturer
    context_object_name = 'lecture_list'
    queryset = Lecturer.objects.select_related(
        'faculty'
    ).prefetch_related('lecture').order_by('lecturer')
```

Since this is a `ListView`, there is no need to add the queryset to the context yourself, you can specify the name of the variable where you pass the queryset with the [**`context_object_name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.context_object_name).